# Change sender when sending email with TIdSmtp

Tags: delphi, email, delphi-xe7, indy10

I'm making an email system for digital marketing and I have a problem to change the sender's name using Indy10, it is always taking the standard name registered in the account. I would like to change this name.

```
var
  IdBody: TIdText;

begin
 with IDSMTP do
  begin
   if Connected then
    Disconnect();
   Host := edtSMTP.Text;
   Password := edtSenha.Text;
   Port := sePorta.Value;
   Username := edtRemetente.Text;
   with IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions do
    begin
     SSLVersions := [];
     if cbxSSLV2.Checked then
      SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv2];
     if cbxSSLV23.Checked then
      SSLVersions := SSLVersions + [sslvSSLv23];
     if cbxSSLV3.Checked then
      SSLVersions := SSLVersions + [sslvSSLv3];
     if cbxTLSV1.Checked then
      SSLVersions := SSLVersions + [sslvTLSv1];
     if cbxTLSV11.Checked then
      SSLVersions := SSLVersions + [sslvTLSv1_1];
     if cbxTLSV12.Checked then
      SSLVersions := SSLVersions + [sslvTLSv1_2];
    end;

   case cbxAutenticacao.ItemIndex of
     1:  UseTLS := utNoTLSSupport;
     2:  UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
     3:  UseTLS := utUseRequireTLS;
     4:  UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
   end;

   Connect;
   Authenticate;
   with IdMessage do
    begin
     MessageParts.Clear;
     Subject := edtAssunto.Text;
     MessageParts.Clear;
     IdBody := TIdText.Create(MessageParts);
     try
      IdBody.ContentType := 'text/html';
      IdBody.Body.Text := mEngenharia.Text;
      if edtAnexo.Text <> '' then
       begin
        if FileExists(edtAnexo.Text) then
         TIdAttachmentFile.Create(MessageParts, TFileName(edtAnexo.Text));
       end;
      From.Address := edtDestinatario.Text;
      Recipients.EMailAddresses := edtDestinatario.Text;
      BccList.EMailAddresses := edtDestinatario.Text;
      Send(IdMessage);
      ShowMessage('Email enviado com sucesso!');
     finally
      FreeAndNil(IdBody);
     end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please show your actual code, and clarify with an example exactly what you are trying to accomplish. `TIdMessage` has `From` and `Sender` properties, and `TIdSMTP` has overloaded `Send()` methods that take an optional `AFrom` parameter, if you want to use a different sender than the one specified in `TIdMessage`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I changed the post, ai wanted the following, in hotmail for example, the first column and the name, and the second the subject, I want to change the name there, put the company eg to inves registered the name in the email

Comment: I see that you set the same email address for the sender as the recipient address, it can be that your SMTP server does not allow this.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I like to do a test, the mail arrives usually so that comes the email owner's name, and wanted to change it

Comment: Using a fake address? That's the tell tale sign of a spammer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And not fake address, and the number of the invoice that want to put

Comment: I m afraid this wont work, your emails will be marked as spam. I feel there is a language barrier here, you need to explain more what you are trying to achieve here..

Comment: Sending email through SMTP from a different sender than the real one is asking to get flagged as spam and have the recipients never receive the message. There are third-party service specifically designed for this purpose, such as Mandrill.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem I see with this code is that you are assigning the same value (`edtDestinatario.Text`) to the `TIdMessage.From.Address`, `TIdMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses`, and `TIdMessage.BccList.EMailAddresses` properties.  You should not be doing that (except when sending test emails to yourself).  You need to set the `TIdMessage.From` property to the name/address of the person who is sending the email, and there is no point in having `TIdMessage.Recipients` and `TIdMessage.BccList` contain the same list of addresses as those recipients will then receive duplicate emails.

If the address of the person who is sending the email is not the same as the owner of the SMTP account you are using to send the email with, you need to set the `TIdMessage.Sender.Address` property, or the optional `AFrom` parameter of the `TIdSMTP.Send()` method, to the account owner's real address.  When `TIdSMTP` sends a `MAIL FROM` command to the server, it has to specify the *actual* sender of the email, which the SMTP server then validates to make sure it is allowed to send email (even if you had already authenticated with the server beforehand).  In that command, `TIdSMTP` specifies the `AFrom` address if provided, otherwise the `TIdMessage.Sender.Address` if provided, otherwise the `TIdMessage.From.Address` address.

The sender that is specified in the `MAIL FROM` command is treated differently than the `From` and `Sender` email headers that `TIdMessage` generates.  In fact, the actual email data that `TIdMessage` generates is sent *as-is* to each recipient, it is just arbitrary data as far as the SMTP server is concerned.  The server is not supposed to mess around with it, other than to insert additional headers for tracking and routing purposes.  So whatever `Name` you assign to the `TIdMessage.From` and `TIdMessage.Sender` properties, that is the name that recipients will see.

```
with IdMessage do
begin
  Clear;
  try
    Subject := edtAssunto.Text;
    if FileExists(edtAnexo.Text) then
    begin
      ContextType := 'multipart/mixed';
      IdBody := TIdText.Create(MessageParts);
      IdBody.ContentType := 'text/html';
      IdBody.Body.Text := mEngenharia.Text;
      TIdAttachmentFile.Create(MessageParts, edtAnexo.Text);
    end else
    begin
      ContentType := 'text/html';
      Body.Text := mEngenharia.Text;
    end;
    From.Address := ...;
    From.Name := ...;
    Sender.Address := ...; // if different than From.Address
    Recipients.EMailAddresses := edtDestinatario.Text;
    Send(IdMessage);
  finally
    Clear;
  end;
  ShowMessage('Email enviado com sucesso!');
end;
```